# convert List to Json in python, so can be accessible by use of Key

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the List into python .

```
list_of_element=['{TC0:{k1:"V1",k2:"V2"}}',
                 '{TC1:{K1:V1,K2:"V2",K3:"V3"}}']
```

I am trying to convert the above format of the list to JSON, So it will be easy to access by using Key each values of "K1"

```
[{
    "TC0": {
        "k1": "V1",
        "k2": "V2"
    }
}, {
    "TC1": {
        "K1": "V1",
        "K2": "V2",
        "K3": "V3"
    }
}]
```

I tried using `json.dumps` it is completely making as string , but I am not able to access something like this

```
json_value=[{
    "TC0": {
        "k1": "V1",
        "k2": "V2"
    }
}, {
    "TC1": {
        "K1": "V1",
        "K2": "V2",
        "K3": "V3"
    }
}]
json_value[0]['TC0']['k1']   # Accessing value like this
```

Comment: It's not valid json

Comment: This is not a valid json. Either you brute force it to a valid json or you ensure you get a valid json

Comment: Make sure you have valid JSON to begin with. Then use `json.loads()`.

Comment: You maybe missed a `:` in the first element of the list.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA that was a typo

Comment: And those strings should be contained by quotation marks .Or `json.loads` couldn't work normally.

Comment: In which your talking ? The Json which I have put is vaid json . I Validated it Online . But the list is NOT in Json format , how can make it json ?

Comment: The string you posted is NOT  a valid JSON string. For a valid json string, all the words are quotted. In your case above, only V1, V2 and V3 are quoted. The rest do not have quotes

Comment: @Onyambu I know .. that is the problem which I need to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that your `json` string is not valid, you could do:

```
import re
update_keys = re.sub(r'(\w+):', '"\\1":', ','.join(list_of_element))
update_vals = re.sub(r':(\w+)', ':"\\1"', update_keys)
```

Now the string is valid. You could either do:

```
list(eval(update_vals)
```

or

```
import re
json.loads(f'[{update_vals}]')
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! Just for more understanding . `update_keys = re.sub(r'(\w+):', '"\\1":', ','.join(list_of_element))` I understood `(\w+):'`, but can you please explain me , what is `'"\\1":'` and `','.join(list_of_element))`. And what is `f` in `f'[{update_vals}]'`

Comment: @ashtav the `"\\1"` is the replacement. ie the first captured group.  Please take a look into regex. ",". join(...), joins a list into a string

Comment: thanks alot . I updated my comment asking regarding , what is `f` and what ur trying

Answer (score 0):

**STRING**: possible work around is to convert your list into a string

```
import json
str='[{"TC0":{"k1":"V1","k2":"V2"}},{"TC1":{"K1":"V1","K2":"V2","K3":"V3"}}]'
my_json = json.loads(str)
print(my_json)
print(my_json[0]['TC0']['k1'])
```

**LIST**: if you need to manage the list, you can use this solution. However the access to values will be a little bit different (see the last line)

```
import json
lst=['{"TC0":{"k1":"V1","k2":"V2"}}','{"TC1":{"K1":"V1","K2":"V2","K3":"V3"}}']

my_json = {'list':[]}
for s in lst:
  tmp_json = json.loads(s)
  my_json['list'].append(tmp_json)

print(my_json)
print(my_json['list'][0]['TC0']['k1'])
```